# Autosys Email Generation if the job runs more than the time specified

Tags: autosys

Currenty I have requirement in my enviroment for the autosys email notifition.

Requirement: If the job runs more than the specified time it should trigger an email.

What I am trying is using max_run_alam, but I am not successful.

Lets say i have a job that runs for 10mins(lets say the time as 10.00). i set max_run_alarm as 3. i should get an email at 10.03 where i can goahead and see why the job is running more than the max_run_alarm. if i use max_run_alarm i am able to see in the logs triggering that alarm, but I cannot spend all day monitoring the logs to see which job is taking long as i have many jobs. my question is am i using max_run_alarm in the correct way or is there something else i am missing or is there entirely different way for the emails to generate.

pls advise.

Answer (score 1):

We are using autosys R11 at work. I believe the triggering of emails is already automated in higher versions of autosys, but, in our version, to send automatic emails after a certain time, we create two extra autosys jobs. One autosys job starts at the same time as the job you want to "monitor". This job contains a 'sleep' command. (in your example, the command would be "sleep 180" for the job to run for 3 minutes until completion). The second extra job is the sending of the email and only starts after successful completion of the sleep-job.

To prevent the mail from being send every time the autosys box starts, you have to add your first job as BOX_SUCCESS condition. The sleep-job will run to completion, but the mail-job went from the "ACTIVATED" state to the "INACTIVE" state because the autosys box isn't RUNNING anymore.