# AUTOSYS jjobs max run alert system

Tags: report, alert, autosys

(Alert) I am new with autosys.

Our team is using autosys version 11.3.5 in remote server(no access to idash).What we are looking for is , if any job is running for more that its mentioned max run time in JIL script , it should email a report containing details of such jobs to a particular mailbox.

Please provide answer with details.So , that a newbie can understand.if possible please provide with the script as we are on tight schedule .
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 1max_run_alarm`of Autosys to set the alarm and it will send an email to the email id that you put as a part of`notification_emailaddress` parameter.

References:
https://wiki.orphicsolutions.com/doku.php?id=autosys:jil

[Autosys Email Generation if the job runs more than the time specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252335/autosys-email-generation-if-the-job-runs-more-than-the-time-specified)